# Getting my name off car loan/title

Tags: loans, title

My fiance left me and married her ex husband 2 months later. We had two financed vehicles. Both in our name. One got repossesed. She took the other one with her.

My questions are: How can I get my name off the title and loan? Is bankruptcy the only way? Can I sue? Am I supposed to be listed on their insurance?

I cant get a car loan because of this. Thanks

Comment: I think you need legal assistance. The general rule is that if you are on the loan you are fully responsible for it. But you may have some recourse against the ex-fiance because you weren't married.

Comment: You are responsible for the loan.  You cannot remove your name from the title unless the loan is paid off.  See https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/44029/co-signed-a-loan-and-i-need-to-have-my-name-removed?rq=1